# Python 2.7 Unit test: Assert logger warning thrown

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, logging, nose

I'm trying to write a Unit Test for a piece of python code that raises a warning via `logger.warn('...')` under certain conditions. How do I assert that this warning has been logged? I noticed that `assertLogged` is not available until at least Python 3.4, unfortunately I am in 2.7.

Answer (score 12):

Python 3.4 Added to unittest exactly that feature. See [TestCase.assertLogs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html?highlight=unittest#unittest.TestCase.assertLogs). The API is really easy to use:

```
with self.assertLogs('foo', level='INFO') as cm:
   logging.getLogger('foo').info('first message')
   logging.getLogger('foo.bar').error('second message')
self.assertEqual(cm.output, ['INFO:foo:first message',
                             'ERROR:foo.bar:second message'])
```

Now, this question is tagged `python2.7` but it will show up when search for similar title for `python + unittest + logging`. And it's pretty easy to back-port that feature to Python2.7, so here it is:

```
# logger_test.py 
# this file contains the base class containing the newly added method
# assertLogs
import collections
import logging
_LoggingWatcher = collections.namedtuple("_LoggingWatcher",
                                         ["records", "output"])

class _BaseTestCaseContext(object):

    def __init__(self, test_case):
        self.test_case = test_case

    def _raiseFailure(self, standardMsg):
        msg = self.test_case._formatMessage(self.msg, standardMsg)
        raise self.test_case.failureException(msg)


class _CapturingHandler(logging.Handler):
    """
    A logging handler capturing all (raw and formatted) logging output.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.watcher = _LoggingWatcher([], [])

    def flush(self):
        pass

    def emit(self, record):
        self.watcher.records.append(record)
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.watcher.output.append(msg)


class _AssertLogsContext(_BaseTestCaseContext):
    """A context manager used to implement TestCase.assertLogs()."""

    LOGGING_FORMAT = "%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s"

    def __init__(self, test_case, logger_name, level):
        _BaseTestCaseContext.__init__(self, test_case)
        self.logger_name = logger_name
        if level:
            self.level = logging._levelNames.get(level, level)
        else:
            self.level = logging.INFO
        self.msg = None

    def __enter__(self):
        if isinstance(self.logger_name, logging.Logger):
            logger = self.logger = self.logger_name
        else:
            logger = self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.logger_name)
        formatter = logging.Formatter(self.LOGGING_FORMAT)
        handler = _CapturingHandler()
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.watcher = handler.watcher
        self.old_handlers = logger.handlers[:]
        self.old_level = logger.level
        self.old_propagate = logger.propagate
        logger.handlers = [handler]
        logger.setLevel(self.level)
        logger.propagate = False
        return handler.watcher

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        self.logger.handlers = self.old_handlers
        self.logger.propagate = self.old_propagate
        self.logger.setLevel(self.old_level)
        if exc_type is not None:
            # let unexpected exceptions pass through
            return False
        if len(self.watcher.records) == 0:
            self._raiseFailure(
                "no logs of level {} or higher triggered on {}"
                .format(logging.getLevelName(self.level), self.logger.name))


class LogTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def assertLogs(self, logger=None, level=None):
        """Fail unless a log message of level *level* or higher is emitted
        on *logger_name* or its children.  If omitted, *level* defaults to
        INFO and *logger* defaults to the root logger.

        This method must be used as a context manager, and will yield
        a recording object with two attributes: `output` and `records`.
        At the end of the context manager, the `output` attribute will
        be a list of the matching formatted log messages and the
        `records` attribute will be a list of the corresponding LogRecord
        objects.

        Example::

            with self.assertLogs('foo', level='INFO') as cm:
                logging.getLogger('foo').info('first message')
                logging.getLogger('foo.bar').error('second message')
            self.assertEqual(cm.output, ['INFO:foo:first message',
                                         'ERROR:foo.bar:second message'])
        """
        return _AssertLogsContext(self, logger, level)
```

Now in your unit-testing modules you can use that class:

```
#test_my_module
from logger_test import LogTestCase

class TestMyModule(LogTestCase):

    def test_some_feature(self):
        with self.assertLogs('foo', level='INFO') as cm:
            logging.getLogger('foo').info('first message')
            logging.getLogger('foo.bar').error('second message')
        self.assertEqual(cm.output, ['INFO:foo:first message',
                         'ERROR:foo.bar:second message'])
```

Answer (score 1):

In your unit test setup, add a logging handler which buffers records, and remove it during teardown. You can use as a basis [a couple of utility classes, `TestHandler` and `Matcher`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/320fbfd40691/Lib/test/support/__init__.py#l1925), which are part of the Python test infrastructure. (The link is to Python's default branch, but the classes should be usable in other Python versions). For information on how to use these classes, see [this post](http://plumberjack.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/unit-testing-and-logging.html).